# place an element in a circular path dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a following three circular div's and i want to place an item in the circular path of a div dynamically based on the items value.

Is there any better way to implement this ? i want to place the item in circular path of a div dynamically.

In the below code, i want to place the div in  circular path which has the class "placeit" .

find the codepen below.
https://codepen.io/najurudeen/full/JJQyzL

```css
    .container{
         width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        background: #282e3d;
        height: 600px; 
      
    }
      .one{
        height: 170px;
        background: #2196F3;
        width: 170px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 4000;
        background: radial-gradient(#86c56f, #30bf9a);
      
    }
    
    .two{
         height: 240px;
        background: #9E9E9E;
        width: 240px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        
        //opacity: 0.4;
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(32,135,153,0.4),rgba(36,133,153,0.5));
      
    }
    
    .three{
      height: 300px;
        background: #E91E63;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        /* position: absolute; */
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(40,67,90,0.4),rgba(41,67,88,0.5));
      
    }
    
    .placeit{
      position:absolute;
      left:90%;
      top:20%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two">
       <div class="placeit">item1 60%</div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <div class="placeit">item2 70%</div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *place the item in circular path of a div dynamically  based on the items value*?

Comment: see the codesnippet, an item has 60% as value so i need to place the item anywhere in second circle.

Comment: So are you saying the inner circle indicates 0% and the outer circle is 100%? I'm not sure if you have your *Item 2* placed correctly so I'm unsure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite ambiguous...when you say dynamically i hope you are talking about having some script in your code...if it is so then where is your script and from where your value is coming...you have not defined anything..and if you are just trying to create a circular graph then maybe this will help:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="one"><p class="center">Item0 75%</p></div>
        <div class="two">
            <p>item1 60%</p>

        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <p>item2 70%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and add this to css:

```
p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.center {
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 170px;
}
```